# A combinatorial argument to prove a general inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, induction

Recently, I have seen the following argument:

$$f(x)  < Dx + f\left(\frac{x}{2} \right)$$

$$\Rightarrow f(x) < Dx + f \left( \frac{x}{2} \right ) < Dx + \frac{Dx}{2} + f \left(\frac{x}{4} \right)$$

$$\Rightarrow f(x) < Dx (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + ...  + \frac{1}{2^n}) + f\left ( \frac{x}{2^n} \right)$$
Since $f(0) = 0$, then taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ gives:

$$f(x) < 2 Dx$$

I was wondering if this could be generalized. My goal is to perform a similar trick on the system of inequalities:

$$f(x)  >  D x - f\left(\frac{x}{a} \right) $$

$$f(x) < Dx - f \left( \frac{x}{a} \right ) + f \left( \frac{x}{b} \right ) + f \left( \frac{x}{c} \right)$$

The first iteration isn't too bad. Replacing the negative terms above by the lower bound and the positive terms above by the upper bound, we get:

$$f(x) < Dx - \frac{Dx}{a} + f \left( \frac{x}{a^2} \right )  + \frac{Dx}{b} - f \left ( \frac{x}{ab} \right ) + f \left ( \frac{x}{b^2}\right) + f \left( \frac{x}{cb} \right )  + \frac{Dx}{c} - f \left ( \frac{x}{ac} \right ) + f \left ( \frac{x}{bc} \right ) + f \left ( \frac{x}{c^2} \right) $$

As you can see, it gets complicated quickly. Again, the goal here is to end up with a statement like $ f(x) < ACx$ for some constant A, presumably in terms of a, b and c $ \in \mathbb{Z}$. Has anyone seen anything like this before / tried to make a similar argument? Any advice, info, suggestions would be very much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Note when you take a limit of an inequality, you get a non-strict inequality. Also, should say $f$ is continuous. The duplicate $f$s means there will be exponentially more $f$s as you iterate the inequality over and over again, which will lead further and further astray from how the situation is resolved with only one $f$. BTW, by bounding $f(x/a)$ from below you can derive $$ f(x)<D(1-1/a)x+f(x/a^2)+f(x/b)+f(x/c). $$ If you define the operator $S_bf(x)=f(x/b)$, you can use the multinomial expansion of $(S_{a^2}+S_b+S_c)^n$ to iterate the inequality.

Comment: @jonan, can you please give more context on this? What is D and why does the first inequality hold? I'm interested in knowing more details.

Comment: @Dunkel, I am looking into Chebyshev's elementary proofs on bounding his function, psi(x), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function  , he often stumbles across inequalities of the first type that I have mentioned above. However, I am modifying his method, and in doing so I find many more inequalities of the second type. Here is the paper I have been reading (it's in french): http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1852_1_17_A19_0.pdf

Comment: @runway44, am I correct to say then that: 

$$f(x) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Dx \left(1 - \frac{1}{a} \right) \cdot \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = n} \frac{n!}{k_1 ! k_2 ! k_3 ! } \frac{1}{a^{2k_1} b^{k_2} c^{k_3}} $$

And if this is the case, is there any way to interpret this limit like we did in the first case?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting that. I'm getting $$ f(x)\le \left[D\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\frac{\displaystyle 1-\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)^n}{\displaystyle 1-\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)}\right]x+\sum_{u+v+w=n}\binom{n}{u,v,w} f\left(\frac{x}{a^{2u}b^vc^w}\right). $$ And unable to take the limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @runway44 would you mind giving a bit more insight as to how you came to this solution? I am trying to generalize to the following case:
$$f(x)  < C_0 x + C_1 f \left ( \frac{x}{n_1} \right ) + ... + C_p f \left ( \frac{x}{n_p} \right )$$
Intuitively, I see why the multinomial formula is relevant, but I just don't see exactly how you used it in your original derivation.

Comment: First step: replace $x$ in $f(x)>Dx-f(x/a)$ with $x/a$ to get $f(x/a)>Dx/a-f(x/a^2)$, then use that to replace $f(x/a)$ in the inequality $f(x)<Dx-f(x/a)+f(x/b)+f(x/c)$ and get $$ f(x)<Dx-Dx/a+f(x/a^2)+f(x/b)+f(x/c). $$ Define the operators $S_bf(x)=f(x/b)$ and $T=S_{a^2}+S_b+S_c$ and the constant $K=D(1-1/a)$. Then this is $f(x)<Kx+Tf(x)$. Iterating this gives $f(x)<Kx+T(Kx+Tf(x))$. Note $T$ is a linear operator, so iterating $n$ times yields $$ f(x)<K(1+T+\cdots+T^{n-1})x+T^nf(x). $$

Comment: Define $L=1/a^2+1/b+1/c$ so $T^kx=L^kx$ and with geometric sum formula on $(1+T+\cdots+T^{n-1})x$ and multinomial expansion on $T^nf(x)$ we get what I mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: @runway44, thank you. This has helped me alot. Somewhat unrelated, but how does this multinomial formula behave in this limit? Specifically, the term on the right. Suppose that $f(0) = 0$, can we say anything about this sum?

Comment: I doubt it. ${}$